# Query for Buffer Cache Hit Ratio

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to compute buffer cache hit ratio and group by instances. For this I have below formula;

```
1 - ( physical reads cache / (consistent gets from cache + db block gets from cache)
```

The query that i need to compute the formula like below;

```
select inst_id,name,value 
from gv$sysstat 
where name in ('consistent gets from cache','db block gets from cache','physical reads cache')
```

I tried to make it using 3 subqueries but it is not useful and not works properly.

The example output of this query like below;

```
1   db block gets from cache    3980038
1   consistent gets from cache  16692788
1   physical reads cache        174385
```

The example output what i want is like below;

```
INST_ID   VALUE
1         0.92   
2         0.93
```

How can i write this query to get cache hit ratio ?

Comment: You do realise that Buffer Cache Hit Ratio is a largely uninformative if not actually discredited metric, don't you? [Find out more](https://richardfoote.wordpress.com/category/buffer-cache-hit-ratio/)

Comment: @APC didn't understand

Comment: Read the article I linked to. BHCR doesn't tell you anything meaningful about the state of your database.

Comment: What APC is trying to say: looking at the buffer cache hit ratio is useless.

Comment: Or in another way; what is it you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @APC Lets say you will analyze a new database which have performance problems. Let's say shared pool much bigger than the buffer cache and it has not enough size to hit ratio. How would you identify the problem in easy way. So, i don't agree

Comment: @johntrue - I'm giving you the best advice I can: it's up to you whether you take it.

Comment: @johntrue - what does the shared pool (SQL cursor cache) have to do with it? Surely BCHR is about cached data (so excluding direct path reads) and not cached SQL?

Comment: @APC okay. Lets email to oracle for delete hit ratio value from the awr report

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use this as a Query For Buffer Cache Hit Radio for a RAC database :

```
select s1.inst_id, s3.value / (s1.value + s2.value) value
  from gv$sysstat s1, gv$sysstat s2, gv$sysstat s3
 where s1.name = 'consistent gets from cache'
   and s2.name = 'db block gets from cache'
   and s3.name = 'physical reads cache'
   and s1.inst_id = s2.inst_id
   and s1.inst_id = s3.inst_id
 order by s1.inst_id;
```

alternatively using ANSI SQL, following query may be used :

```
select s1.inst_id, s3.value / (s1.value + s2.value) value
  from gv$sysstat s1 join gv$sysstat s2 on ( s1.inst_id = s2.inst_id ) 
                     join gv$sysstat s3 on ( s1.inst_id = s3.inst_id )
 where s1.name = 'consistent gets from cache'
   and s2.name = 'db block gets from cache'
   and s3.name = 'physical reads cache'
 order by s1.inst_id;
```